# How to associate type with number as parameter to function?

Tags: c++

Consider this example:

> In a game there are some buildings you can build with a specific cost for each kind . for example a "House" can be built with the cost of 2 "Iron" and 3 "Wood" ; in which "Iron" and "Wood" are "Resources" pre-defined (there is "Resources" interface and "wood" and "Iron" and ... inherit from it ) .And there are other buildings with different types and different number of each "Resource".

I have a function for building such buildings. How can I pass the cost of each building to it so it would check if the player has these "Resources" and decrease the number from player's "Resources"?

Cost of each building should be in its class. How to declare such variable that shows number and type (class Resource)?

One obvious option is to declare a 2D array, where the first row represents the kind of "Resource" and the second row represents the number.

Is there any other option than this?

Comment: Your 2D array is pretty much the way it should be done. If there are many types of resources, a std::map may be more efficient.

Comment: @SvenNilsson Yeah. map is a good idea. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're wanting to map between building type and resource counts, so how about some kind of function that returns the mapping explicitly as a vector? Using a struct to keep track of it rather than a 2d array might be more maintainable and easier to follow:

```
enum class Resource {
    Iron,
    Wood,
    ...
}

enum class Building {
    House,
    Tower,
    ...
}

struct ResourceCount {
    Resource resource;
    size_t count;
};

std::vector<ResourceCount> get_resource_count(Building b) {
    switch (b) {
    case Building::House:
        return std::vector{
            ResourceCount{Resource::Iron, 50},
            ResourceCount{Resource::Wood, 1000},
            ...
        };
    case Building::Tower:
        return std::vector{
            ResourceCount{Resource::Iron, 500},
            ResourceCount{Resource::Wood, 10},
            ...
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this approach. Nice

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure if I understood the questions correctly. I assume you are looking for some meaningful/readable code instead of declaring arrays. In that case you an declare the buildign as a structure with resources as its elements and pass that as a parameter instead.

```
struct Building
{
   int costIron;
   int costWood;
}

Building building;

void startbuilding(Building building);
{
   //Use the interface building.ironCost and building.ironWood
}
```

Comment: My buildings are already classes not structures. and this approach will cause difficulty in changing the code in the future